# ListView load more at scroll begin

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-cursor

I'm trying to implement some chat activity.
Messages must be ordreded from older to newest (new messages on a bottom, older on a top of my ListView), for that i'm using `android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"` and `android:stackFromBottom="true"` on my layout.
When user scroll to up ListView should be updated from older messages from my SQL database. Here is some code:

```
 public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Object data) {
        final Cursor cursor = (Cursor)data;

        if(cursor.getCount() > API_REQUEST_COUNT) {
            this.lsView.setStackFromBottom(false);
        }

        this.mAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);

        if(this.mAdapter.getCount() > 0) {
           this.isLoading = false;                
            }, 500);
        }
    }
```

And this is how i implement Load More function:

```
 this.lsView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int currentItemPosition = totalItemCount - firstVisibleItem;

            // TODO without refreshing cache :-(
            if(totalItemCount == 0 && !isLoading) {
                isLoading = true;

                if(getLoaderManager().getLoader(loaderId) != null) {
                    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(loaderId, getArguments(), ConversationFragment.this);
                } else {
                    getLoaderManager().initLoader(loaderId, getArguments(), ConversationFragment.this);
                }

                // TODO pagination
                ApiManager.getInstance().getDialog(dialogId, pageNum);
            }

            if(!isLoading && totalItemCount != 0 && currentItemPosition == (API_REQUEST_COUNT * pageNum) - 1) {
                pageNum++;

                ApiManager.getInstance().getDialog(dialogId, pageNum);
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is, when i update my adapter `ListView` scroll to up, but i want that he freezes on a current position.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

after loading the New Data into Adpater this should work fine

```
 this.lsView.setSelection(this.mAdapter.getCount() - 1);
```

for that Try this,this will retain the scroll position

```
if(listView.getAdapter()==null)
   listView.setAdapter(this.mAdapter);
else{
   this.myAdapter.updateData(myNewData); //update your adapter's data
   this.myAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this line should scroll to bottom my listview after update. But i want to stay on current position after update

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                scrollState = scrollState1;
                isScrollCompleted();

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem1,
                    int visibleItemCount1, int totalItemCount1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 firstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem1;
                    visibleItemCount = visibleItemCount1;
                    totalItemCount=totalItemCount1;

            }
        });
```

this is isScrollCompleted().

```
private void isScrollCompleted() {

        if(arrayList.size()>20)
        {
            Log.v("firstVisible", firstVisibleItem+"");
            Log.v("visibli", "item count"+visibleItemCount);
            Log.v("ScrollState", "scrollState"+scrollState);
            Log.v("total", totalItemCount+"");
            int lastInScreen=firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount;
            if (lastInScreen == totalItemCount && scrollState == 0) {
                start=start+20;
                //get new twenty recornd in list and notify adapter
                cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.v("arrayList", "size="+arrayList.size());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Store the firstVisible position item index  at the time of more data
>   loading (when reached at top of ListView). when data loaded
>   successfully then   set this value position to first Selected item
>   using:-

```
setSelection(index);
```

> If it not solve your problem Then let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem.
The solution that worked for me was before adding the new items to change the TranscriptMode:

```
listView.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
```

After adding:

```
//inserted= number of inserted items
listView.setSelection(inserted+firstVisibleItem);
```

and in the onScrollStateChanged and onScroll I put the TranscriptMode back to the original:

```
if (inserted>0) {
listView.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
inserted = 0;
}
```